# return in an event function results in alert pop-up

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I am following a book on JavaScript. The page that puzzles me is the following: http://javascriptbook.com/code/c06/html5-events.html.

When the user pressed "Next" button an event fires. This is the code that specifies event listener:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) {
  var message = 'You have changes that have not been saved';
  (event || window.event).returnValue = message;
  return message;
})
```

This code results in an alert and offers me to **Stay on this page** or **Leave**.  I don't get the syntax here. I thought that alerts are made with `alert()` function. What is going or here? Thanks for your help

Comment: That alert-like popup is the whole point of the "beforeunload" event.

Comment: oh, didn't know that. I still don't get how the return value ends up in alert

Comment: The code that calls the event handler puts it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code returns a message, so browser takes care of confirming the user for navigation( or close) event, also that is why you get browser specific alert.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) {
  var message = 'You have changes that have not been saved';
  (event || window.event).returnValue = message;
  return message; // alerts with this message.
});
```

If you try below code, which doesnt returns the message, then you won't get confirmation alert box, but you can still capture the event And do stuff.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) {
  //var message = 'You have changes that have not been saved';
  //(event || window.event).returnValue = message;
  localStorage.eventCaptured = 'eventCaptured without alert'; // gets saved to localStorage
  //return message;
})
```